# How to handle multiple images upload in vapor 4?

Tags: swift, file-upload, vapor

Here is the `Html` codes:

```html
<form method="POST" action="/create" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="imgs">Images</label>
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="imgs" id="imgs" multiple/>
  </div>
</form>
```

And Codes below are vapor 4. I got an empty array if:

```swift
struct Request: Content {
      let imgs: [Data] //or [File]
}
```

I got a whole `Data` if:

```swift
struct Request: Content {
      let imgs: Data
}
```

But how to split a `Data` to multiple images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By standard for multiple files `name` should contain `[]`

Try this form

```html
<form method="POST" action="/create" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="imgs">Images</label>
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="imgs[]" id="imgs" multiple/>
  </div>
</form>
```

and then in Vapor

```swift
struct Request: Content {
    let imgs: [File] //or [Data]
}
```